# Spring Boot 3 with resiliance4j and openfeign

Tags: java, spring, resilience4j, openfeign

I use:

```
  implementation "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-openfeign"
  implementation "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-circuitbreaker-resilience4j"
```

and my configs

```
spring:
  cloud:
    openfeign:
      client:
        circuitBreaker:
          enabled: true
```

and

```
resilience4j:
  circuitbreaker:
    configs:
      default:
        registerHealthIndicator: true            
        slidingWindowType: TIME_BASED            
        slidingWindowSize: 15                   
        minimumNumberOfCalls: 10                 
        failureRateThreshold: 100               
        waitDurationInOpenState: 6000            
        permittedNumberOfCallsInHalfOpenState: 3 
        eventConsumerBufferSize: 50
```

My feign client looks like

```
@FeignClient("service_name")
@CircuitBreaker(name = "default")
public interface ServiceFeignClient {

  @PostMapping(value = "/v1/something")
  ResponseEntity<A> method(Request request);
```

and when I simulate failures the CircuitBreaker closes everything is OK.
But when I remove

```
@CircuitBreaker(name = "default")
```

Nothing happens. I have 10 feignClients and do not want to name them **default**
Is there a way to name them automatically and to apply the config at once?
Can I apply CircuitBreaker annotation on all my feign clients programatically?